# Generate code coverage reports for Android Maven Library Project

Tags: android, maven, android-library, emma

I have a Android Library project and an Android Test project.
The test project has Android dependency and junit dependency.

The modules are:

- MyProject
- MySample
- MyProjectTest

MySample uses MyProject as a library and gives an apk as output.
MyProjectTest has MySample as dependency and it has the test cases.
The unit test cannot run on jvm. That is why MySample project is used which generates an apk and the unit tests can run on the emulator. They run as instrumented tests as they need an emulator to execute.

There are lots of documentation available for an ant build but very few for maven android project.
I have configured emma for code coverage, but the coverage files are not generated.

My poms follow this link.https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/EmmaMaven with the following modification.

- The tested.project.dir is set to MySample
- /data/data/(package of MySample)/files/coverage.ec in property pullSource

I get the error: "Cannot pull coverage.ec from device as it doesnt exist."

Please help. Any pointer to the same is much appreciated.
Also I am open to any coverage tools. My only constraint is I need to test Maven Android Library Project.
I tried with cobertura too but still couldnt generate any coverage reports.

Comment: I am able to generate the coverage.ec and coverage.em files.
However I am having issues in reporting the coverage through sonar.
I get the Unit Test Success report, Package tangle index, Violations etc
But the Unit tests coverage displays a -(dash). The sonar report generation log doesn't show any error. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: I am able to get the coverage reports if its an application project. But for a library project, the coverage.em file is not generated. Any clue how to generate coverage reports for Android Library Projects. I am not inclined to any coverage tool in particular.